# Best data structure for a sequence of digits [0:9]

Tags: c++, string, digit, std-bitset

What's the best data type that can handle a sequence of digits [0:9] in c++ with the least possible waste in memory?

I think it may be something like that

```
typedef bitset<4> Digit;
vector<Digit> myVector;
```

but I think that each `bitset<4>` reserves a byte -the same as a char-, so it's not better than a normal string, is it?

Are there any better idea to handle something like that?

Comment: What are you trying to do? As this is written I'm unable to figure that out.

Comment: Write a wrapper over `std::vector<unsigned char>` to store two digits per byte maybe? But why do you need it? `std::vector<unsigned char>` with one digit per byte sounds a lot more convenient..

Comment: I'm trying to implement a BigInt class, but I want to build it with the least possible waste, so I want to find something better than std::string.
@Mgetz

Comment: to store in `the least possible waste in memory`, each digit will occupy 4 bit (one nibble) , you could use one char to store 2 digits. One in MSB nibble and another in LSB nibble. In this way worst possible case (odd number of digit ) your one nibble will be unoccupied. WARNING Doing this way the code will be less manageable.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think it may be a good choice.

Comment: Anything that you use that's smaller than a byte is going to incur overhead for encoding/decoding, making any operations you perform on your numbers slower. I'm not sure it's worth the tradeoff.

Comment: Thanks guys I got it.
But why the question got -1 :"(
-I hope things won't get worse-

Comment: Why are you using decimal digits in your class?

Answer (score 3):

To store a value from a set of 10, 4bits are required.

But on 4 bits, 16 values can be represented. That is a waste of 6/16 =37.5%.

So the best representation would minimize the amount of waste.

The best way is to store in binary, where all the combinations of bits are utilized.